# ggplot2; Adding points from a different dataset and a raster/matrix data to a plot of a spatialpolygonsdataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried this but i get Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found. pj4s is an object containing the projection in latlong.

my code

```
fx.ggplot<-function(ctry,aesfill="id",scalefill="Country",pathcol="white"){
    #ctry is a shapefile of countries
     ctry@data$id = rownames(ctry@data)
    ctry.points = fortify(ctry, region="id")
    ctry.df = join(ctry.points, ctry@data, by="id")
    (txt<-paste("p<-ggplot(ctry.df) + aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=",aesfill,")"))
    eval(parse(text=txt))
    p<-p+   geom_polygon() +
        geom_path(color=pathcol) +
        coord_equal() +
        scale_fill_brewer(scalefill)
    return(p)
}

#generate a grid of points
xo<-seq(25,45,0.5)
yo<-seq(-15,5,0.5)
head(xy<-cbind(expand.grid(xo,yo)));names(xy)<-c("lon","lat")
head(xy.sp <- SpatialPoints(xy,proj4string=pj4s))
Overlay<-over(xy.sp,ctry)
xy<-xy[!apply(Overlay, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x))),]

#plot
(p<-fx.ggplot(ctry))
```

[image: This is the plot of the countries returned by (p)]

```
(P<-p+geom_point(data=xy, aes(x=lon, y=lat))) #addpoints returns Error

ggplot()+geom_point(data=xy, aes(x=lon, y=lat)) #This plots the points (as below) without error but in a new plot.
```

[image: Plot of the Points was successful]

```
#matrix
mat.ctry<-fx.polygon2raster2array(shp=ctry,xo,yo,cTim=1)
mat<-cbind(expand.grid(xo,yo),c(mat.ctry));names(mat)<-c(names(xy),"Z")
mat<-mat[!apply(mat, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x))),]
p+geom_raster(data=mat,aes(x=lon,y=lat,colour="red"))
```

#returns Error
yet `ggplot()+geom_raster(data=mat,aes(x=lon,y=lat,colour="red"))` returns what is expected.
[image: Here is the result]

**So where am i failing?**

Comment: Does your dataset `xy` contain a variable called `group`?  The error indicates that you might not, but `P` appears to have `group` as an aesthetic (based on the function you built it with).

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, I wanted to point out that rather and building a string with the ggplot code and eval/parsing it, you can use `aes_string`. Instead of `aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=",aesfill,")"` use `aes_string(x="long", y="lat", fill=aesfill, group="group")` as part of a regular ggplot call.

Comment: @aosmith, if i have a data set xy with just 2 columns (x and y values of points to plot); how then do i add this group variable? I tried an arbitrary `xy$group<-as.factor(1)` but when i plotted `(P<-p+geom_point(data=xy, aes(x=lon, y=lat,group=group)))`  i still got an error. a different one this time. __Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale__

Comment: Put `group=1` in the `aes()` call inside the `geom_raster()`, I think. But without `ctry`, it's not reproducible/testable.

Comment: Thanks again, but while this `(p<-fx.ggplot(ctry))` still works ok, This `(p<-fx.ggplot(ctry)+geom_raster(data=xy, aes(x=lon, y=lat,group=1)))` returns __Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Country' not found__ What does country have to do with the second expression?

Comment: @BrianDiggs gave you a very nice answer.  Now that he created a reproducible example, I can see that you needed to set both `group` and `fill` to NULL in the aesthetics of `geom_point`.  This is because you used `group` and `fill` as overall aesthetics but `xy` doesn't contain the variables group and id that are needed for them. Example: `fx.ggplot(ctry) + geom_point(data = xy,aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = NULL, fill = NULL))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down what is going on and fix some things. First, load the necessary libraries for the code/example.

```
library("rgeos")
library("sp")
library("ggplot2")
library("plyr")
```

Looking at your example map, I figured out which east African countries you had. I pulled shape files for them from the `rworldmap` package. These may not be as nice as your shape files, but they will do for now.

```
library("rworldmap")
data(countriesLow)
ctry <- countriesLow[countriesLow$ISO3.1 %in% c("TZA", "KEN", "UGA", "RWA", "BDI"),]
```

Create the grid of points you had. I tidied up the code some, dropping some calls to `head` and simplifying the subsetting code.

```
#generate a grid of points
xy<-expand.grid(long=seq(25,45,0.5),lat=seq(-15,5,0.5))
xy.sp <- SpatialPoints(xy, proj4string=CRS(proj4string(ctry)))
Overlay<-over(xy.sp,ctry)
xy<-xy[!is.na(Overlay$ISO3.1),]
```

Now your `fx.ggplot` call can be re-written as

```
fx.ggplot<-function(ctry, aesfill="id", scalefill="Country", pathcol="white") {
    ##ctry is a shapefile of countries
    ctry@data$id = rownames(ctry@data)
    ctry.points = fortify(ctry, region="id")
    ctry.df = join(ctry.points, ctry@data, by="id")
    ggplot(ctry.df, aes(long, lat)) +
        geom_polygon(aes_string(group="group", fill=aesfill)) +
        geom_path(colour = pathcol) +
        scale_fill_brewer(scalefill)
}
```

The overall `aes` is just `long` and `lat`; `geom_polygon` needs the additional aesthetics `group` and `fill`, and those are set using `aes_string` since the name of the variable for fill is being passed into the function.

```
(p <- fx.ggplot(ctry))
```

[image]

There are some artifacts in this version but that is (likely) do the shape file I was using; I didn't see them in the plot you showed, so you should not have a problem with that.

```
p + geom_point(data=xy)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a Million. Cool answer. Its 01:33 here and i can go home now :)

Comment: Tomorrow i grapple with adding a lakes layer (polygon)!!

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else can't get the accepted answer work for them: a key is what @aosmith noted in a comment to the original question.

Adding the `geom_point(data=xy)` creates a new layer on the plot. `ggplot2` expects this new layer to match all the aesthetics of the original layer, so you have to specifically define any differences. In this case, the original `geom_polygon` layer uses `group` and `fill` aesthetics but the `geom_point` layer does not. Therefore, you must specify `group=NULL` and `fill=NULL` for `geom_point`, like so:

```
(myplot + geom_point(data=xy, aes(group=NULL, fill=NULL)))
```